# pi4 How can I get in normal mode from out safe mode

Tags: init

I was trying install KDE-PLASMA desktop and therefor I made a mistake with adding a different overlay and after that I get a blackscreen while booting. Now I am in safemode but what I really want is to get in raspi-config for to made changes for the GPL driver. I als tried to use pico in safemode with pico boot/config.txt but then I receive an error that it is a directory and not writeable. I also tried to startx in safemode but then I don't have permission.
Is there a way from out safemode to get in init 2 or init 3 or using mc in safemode

Thanks

Comment: Hi @input, Welcome, and nice to meet you. Ah, let me see. I think it is very unlikely raspi-config can solve your problem. You might like to let us know any, if any, of your old Rpi/Plasma /boot/config.txt or similarly related files, so that we know you old config. Or you can just wait a couple of more months for v5.18 LTS coming out.

Comment: What operating system do you use? If using Raspbian there is no init 2 or init 3. How do you start safemode? Please address me with @Ingo, otherwise I won't see your reply.

Comment: Could you also add the commands you ran to install KDE-PLASMA and setup the overlay you mentioned to your question? This would help us in tracking down what went wrong.